# Breaking apart a string in PHP into three parts

Tags: php

I have a serial number string I need to break apart into 3 parts.

The serial numbers look like this:

FOOB123456AB
BAR789123BC

First part: A-Z letters of variable length
Middle part: 6 digit numerical string
Last part: 2 digit letters

How can I break this apart using PHP so I can work with each individual part?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression can help here. See [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Try:

```
$regex = "/^([a-z]*)([\d]{6})(.*)$/i";
$serial = "FOOB123456AB";
$result = preg_match($regex, $serial, $matches);

// result in $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3]
```

This assumes one serial number per string. If you don't have that, text is easy to break up with `explode()` or similar, and then iterate over the resulting array.